# Pip path added to PATH (environment variable) but still can't be ru

Tags: python, powershell, pip

I am using windows powershell and i need to install pip. While I have been able to do so, it won't let me run. I try to fix the error by adding it to the PATH as suggested by the log but to no avail. May i know how to fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH34z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJbb1.png)

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Comment: When, exactly, did you edit the PATH environment?  Did you start the command window and **then** add the PATH ?  That won't work.  The command window only knows about the PATH that existed when it was started.

Comment: You have to start a new shell after you alter the environment variables.  That doesn't change the variables in the shell you were running.

Comment: Mr Gordon and Roberts' answers is right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add py or python before command
py -m pip help or
python -m pip help

Comment: Why?  `pip` is an actual command.

Comment: pip is python module, to run python module you need to call python interpreter, -m tells Python to run a library module as a script, this allows you to use a module, such as pip, which is usually a library, as if it were a standalone command.
Without the py or python command, your terminal or command prompt wouldn't understand that it needs to launch Python and use it to run the specified module. Instead, it might attempt to find a standalone executable named pip, which is different from the pip module designed to be run within the Python environment.

Comment: _it might attempt to find a standalone executable named pip_ Yes that is exactly what he wants.

Comment: @JohnGordon it is not *necessary*, but it *is recommended*, because `pip.exe` is just a wrapper executable for the module - and a rather limited one. Using `python -m` (or `py -m` accomplishes two things: 1) it ensures that the Pip used corresponds to the Python installation named by `python` (or found by `py`); 2) on Windows, it enables Pip to upgrade itself (if the running process is `pip.exe`, Windows will not allow it to replace the `pip.exe` file on disk).

Comment: That said, this answer is unrelated to the reported problem. The problem is that OP believes the PATH has been set, but it has not actually been. The linked duplicate explains why, and how to fix it.